# Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test JEST testing Express

Tags: express, heroku, jestjs, heroku-postgres, supertest

Im trying to write tests for heroku app, which uses postresql, but looks like my tests functions cannot connect to the database. The endpoints itself are working fine and I receive response from the server when I test it on the browser. Thanks in advance!!
my code: 
server.js

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';

import mountRouter from './routes/index.js';

const port = 7000;
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

mountRouter(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome. The connection has been established.");
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Test passed.");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening`)
  })

export default app;
```

index.js

```js
import patientsRouter from './patients.js';
import staffMembersRouter from './staffMembers.js';
import hospitalWardsRouter from './hospitalWards.js';
import authenticationRouter from './authentication.js';

const mountRouter = app => {
    app.use('/patients', patientsRouter)
    app.use('/staff', staffMembersRouter)
    app.use('/wards', hospitalWardsRouter)
    app.use('/authentication', authenticationRouter)
}

export default mountRouter;
```

hospitalWardsController.js

```js
import pool from '../db/db.js';
import sqlTemplate from 'sql-template-strings';

const { SQL } = sqlTemplate;

class HospitalWardsController {

    getAllHospitalWards = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const allHospitalWards = await pool.query(SQL`
                SELECT * FROM hospital_ward;
                `);

            res.status(200).json(allHospitalWards.rows);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }

    getFreeBedsCount = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { hospital_ward } = req.body;
            const freeBedsCount = await pool.query(SQL`
                SELECT hospital.name AS hospital_name, hospital.location AS hospital_location, hospital_ward.name AS hospital_ward_name, (bed_quantity - bed_reserved) AS beds_free
                FROM hospital_ward
                INNER JOIN hospital
                ON hospital_ward.hospital_id = hospital.id
                WHERE hospital_ward.name = ${hospital_ward}
                ORDER BY beds_free DESC;
            `);
            
            res.status(200).json(freeBedsCount.rows);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
}

const hospitalWardsController = new HospitalWardsController();

export default hospitalWardsController;
```

wards.test.js

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import hospitalWardsController from '../routes/hospitalWards.js';
import app from '../server.js';




    describe("hospitalWards.js TESTS", () => {
    
        describe("hospitalWards.js GET('/') method TEST",  () => {           
   
            test("should return all hospital wards", async () => {
                app.listen();
                                
                const response = await request(hospitalWardsController).get("/").send({});
                expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
             });                               
        });
    });
```